# How to design Multi-User Desktop Application in C# with MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, winforms, desktop-application

I'm in process of doing POC in.net windows form app with MS SQL database.

- This app will be installed in client desktop 300+ machines and it will run on startup.
- This app will be running in background in the client machines.
- For every 15 mins, .net windows app push the client data to SQL server.

Below are my questions

1. For above scenario, which architecture will suits better?(considering scalability and robustness)
2. How to configure and connect the .net window app with SQL DB to hold the 300+ concurrent connections without impacting the performance and timeouts?

Comment: There is not enough detail in your question. If you execute many poorly optimized queries on big data then you can have performance problems. Simple inserts on tables optimized for inserting will certainly run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Total non issues.

1: Irrelevant. 300 connections is nothing to optimize. I would still go through a server with a REST interface, but that has overhead in development. You focus on scalability here- the issue is maintenance and configuratbility and security. Robustness is something a DBA handles and a programmer - reconnecting after connection drops, have data cached in case you can not push it (and yes, wit h300 cliets not all will ALWAYS nave network connection). This is an architectural issue that you provide not enough info to handle.

2: do not run it on a low end phone. Any decent server has way more than enough RAM to handle 300 connections (which I remember reading take like 64kb each - make the match, that is not even 20mb). Given that this pushes data every 15 minutes - and not at the same millisecond - this is a no load situation. Like zero load.

You really seem to have a misunderstanding how crappy modern machines are. You ask for scaling advice on a load that basically a mobile phone abused as a server can handle. I have seen mid range server with 20k connections - that is 20.000.

Timeouts are not a configuring issue - they are a programming issue, for a situation that low loaded. I can force timeout with one connection or two, if I program crappy enough.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Just to clarify. There is no mobile app involved here. This is pure .net desktop native application. all 300+ clients always connected with network (LAN). Hence there may be a chance of concurrent connection to SQL DB from client. Hence requesting advice on the design

Comment: Hence it still is a non issue. Seirously. Forget whatever crappy laptop you use - heck, even it could handle 1000 connections. 300 is LOW. And LAN will NOT be always connected. Do you have ANY esperience? Equipment fails. Sometimes a LAN will have problems. Your applicaiton must handle this. I never assumed Mobile, but I do assume for example a short interrruption while the switches get firmware upgrades ;)